# UnsatisfiedLinkError at JNI invocation

Tags: java, c++, dll, java-native-interface, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I've already found a lot of things and questions about UnsatisfiedLinkError in combination with JNI but none of them could help me out though.
I'm trying to hide a window using Java, so I need 3 WinAPI functions.

I have the following Java source:

```
package hide.window;
public class HideWindow {

    public native static int hideWindow(char[] windowTitle);

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("hideWindow");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("loadLibrary was successful");
        System.out.println(hideWindow("Session Window - Windows Internet Explorer".toCharArray()));
    }
}
```

Then I have my hide_window_HideWindow.h generated by javah.
There's one thing I had to change, because it didn't find the jni.h file in the library path so I just put it into my project and included it the following way:

```
#include "jni.h"
```

**May this cause my Error??**
The whole file:

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include "jni.h"
/* Header for class hide_window_HideWindow */

#ifndef _Included_hide_window_HideWindow
#define _Included_hide_window_HideWindow
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     hide_window_HideWindow
 * Method:    hideWindow
 * Signature: ([C)I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_hide_window_HideWindow_hideWindow
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jcharArray);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

The code I compiled to my DLL looks as follows:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "hide_window_HideWindow.h"
using namespace std;

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_hide_window_HideWindow_hideWindow(char windowTitle[20])
{
    HWND windowHandle = FindWindowA(NULL, windowTitle);
    if (windowHandle){
        if (IsWindowVisible(windowHandle)){
            ShowWindow(windowHandle, 0);
            return 0;
        }
        else{
            ShowWindow(windowHandle, 1);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

There's no difference between a call from eclipse and the following call via cmd (Path is correct):

```
java -Djava.library.path=.. hide.window.HideWindow
```

The resulting output looks like that:

> ```
> loadLibrary was successful
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: hide.window.HideWindow.hideWindow([C)I
>   at hide.window.HideWindow.hideWindow(Native Method)
>   at hide.window.HideWindow.main(HideWindow.java:12)
> ```

That indicates to me that the Java program is able to load the DLL but it fails at the function call. 
I use Eclipse as Java and Codeblocks as C++ IDE, and I have already added the following to the mingw build options.

```
-Wl,--kill-at
```

I hope this question is not too stupid and thank you in advance,
Tom

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the prototype:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_hide_window_HideWindow_hideWindow
    (JNIEnv *, jobject, jcharArray);
```

and your implementation:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_hide_window_HideWindow_hideWindow
    (char windowTitle[20])
```

Of course there's an `UnsatisfiedLinkError` because you didn't implement the correct function.

So you would need something like:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_hide_window_HideWindow_hideWindow
    (JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jcharArray windowTitle)
```

And to get the chars out of the array have a look at `GetPrimitiveArrayCritial` or `GetCharArrayRegion`.

The generated header also look suspicious to me, because you defined the Java method to be `static` but the generated prototype wants to pass a `jobject` ... static methods need `jclass` (because there is no instance object for static method calls):

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_hide_window_HideWindow_hideWindow
    (JNIEnv* env, jclass clazz, jcharArray windowTitle)
```

Another thing: Java's `char` (`jchar`) is an `unsigned int16`, C/C++ `char` is signed or unsigned `int8`. So it might be better to pass a `String` (`jstring`) and get the contents as an UTF8 string using `GetStringUTFChars`.

Comment: Would you mind taking a look at this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18693949/jni-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-same-dll-but-different-location ^^